# Black overlay appears when reloading the page on Android Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

After reloading or refreshing the page (https://vid.world/) on Chrome, it shows a black overlay and when you scroll the page, the overlay disappears.

This only happens on Android phones with the latest version of Chrome (Version: 72.0.3626.105)

**Note**: Site is working fine with other browser and phones.

Comment: It's working for me.

Comment: Are you checking on Latest Chrome on Android ?

Comment: Yes I have latest version.